# sql how get the timezone using country code 'US'

Tags: mysql, sql

how get the timezone in sql using country code like 'US' to my timezone 'Europe/Paris'.

**Example**
From:
Original air date '2017-11-11 20:00:00'
Original country 'US'

To:
My timezone 'Europe/Paris'

Comment: US are spread over more than one timezone

Comment: why do you need that in mysql?

Comment: What about daylight savings?

Comment: The states in the United States cover 6 timezones -- and with daylight saving time, this goes to 12 (https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/usa).  Dependencies and territories add a whole lot more.  (McMurdo Base in Antarctica, for instance, is on New Zealand time.)

Comment: I am working on an calendar to see airing episodes of a tv show....

Comment: @BenfMaappy : Time zone is not directly dependent on country. If you are on a windows machine, go to date and time settings from task bar -> Change time zone , You will always see the names of the cities worldwide along with their UTC offset, rather than countries.